# Getting Top 3 values for each id and status

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I have data something like this,

```
ID        Time        Status
---       ----        ------
1          10           B
1          20           B
1          30           C
1          70           C
1         100           B
1         490           D
```

The desired result should be,

```
ID      Time       Status
1        490         D
1        100         B
1         70         C
```

This is how,I should get top 3 Time vales for ID and distinct status.
For this I Tried:-

```
    ;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS rn
   FROM MyTable
)
SELECT  id,TIME,Status                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
FROM cte
where rn<=3
```

But it doesn't meet my requirement iam gettng top 3 duplicates staus values,How can i solve this.Help!

Comment: From your desired output, it looks like you need top "1" record for each status. (or even a combination of <id, status>.

TOP 3 is misleading, if I just read the data mentioned in your question.

Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Partition by `status` as well:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, status
                                ORDER BY TIME DESC
                               ) AS rn
      FROM MyTable t
     )
SELECT id, TIME, Status 
FROM t
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

The with ties argument of the top function will return all the of the rows which match the top values:

`select top (3) with ties id, Time, Status from table1 order by Time desc`

Alternatively, if you wanted to return 3 values only, but make sure they are always the same 3 values, then you will need to use something else as a tie-breaker. In this case, it looks like your id column could be unique.

`select top (3) id, Time, Status  from table1 order by Time desc, id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct id,max(time) over (partition by id,status) as time ,status
from mytable t order by time desc
```

Output -

```
id  time    status
1   490     D
1   100     B
1   70      C
```

**EDIT**:

```
select distinct TOP 3 id,max(time) over (partition by id,status) as time,status 
from mytable t order by time desc
```

Comment: In case I had another status 'E' having time 5,I should display only top 3 how could i do that now? @Anagha

Comment: That means every time you want only top 3 rows?

Comment: Yes,Top 3 for every distinct status

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [Id] = 1 ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

This will give you top three records for `ID = 1`. For any other ID, just change the number in `WHERE` clause.

Additionally you can make some stored procedure to `UNION` all top three records for each ID - this can be done using looping through all distinct IDs in your table :)

Comment: This will work for the sample data but what happens when there is 200 ids and you want it for each one? That was the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RANK`. 
You may use the below query to get your desired result.

```
select * from 
(select *, RANK() over(partition by status order by time desc) as rn from myTable)T
where rn = 1
```

[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/EMPQH31617)